# My json file can't count the tweet's words

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy

I've studied Python only for a short time, so I'm practicing through other persons' examples. I want to do word filtering on Twitter, its Python code may be summarized as follows.

```
enter code hereimport tweepy
import simplejson as json
from imp import reload
import sys
import re

reload(sys)

consumer_key = 'blah'
consumer_skey = 'blah'
access_tokenA = 'blah'
access_stoken = 'blah'

def get_api():
 api_key = consumer_key
 api_secret = consumer_skey
 access_token = access_tokenA
 access_token_secret = access_stoken
 auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_secret)
 auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
 return auth

class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CustomStreamListener, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.count = 0
    with open('C:\PYTHON\\restrictword.txt') as f:
        self.common = set(line.strip() for line in f)
    self.all_words = {}
    self.pattern = re.compile("[^\w]")
 def on_status(self, status):
    print ('I got a Tweet!')
    self.count += 1
    tweet = status.text
    words = tweet.split()
    for word in words:
        if len(word) > 2 and word != '' and word not in self.common:
            if word not in self.all_words:
                self.all_words[word] = 1
            else:
                self.all_words[word] += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
 l = CustomStreamListener()
 try:
    auth = get_api()
    s = "Obama"
    twitterStreaming = tweepy.Stream(auth, l)
    twitterStreaming.filter(track=[s])
 except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ('-----total tweets as follows-----')
    print (l.count)
    json_data = json.dumps(l.all_words, indent=4)
    with open('word_data.json','w') as f:
        print >> (f), json_data
        print (s)
```

That code can execute successfully because I can see the Console which displays  'I got a tweet!'. According to my python book, `json file(word_data)` must count the words such as `'Obamacare : 5; America : 10;'`. But my `json` file is empty. How can my `json` file count the tweet's words?

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the python write function to write into a file instead ur printing it.

```
  with open(“hello.txt”, “w”) as f: 
  f.write(“Hello World”)
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand your advice. But I don't know what I put them in f.write(??).. I want to that json file collect the words from tweet which related to 'Obama'.

Comment: i dont understand what r u saying can u please type again ?